# RoR - Model.all, but without created_at and updated_at fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am new to Ruby, so this question might look stupid for you, yeah. But still...
I got a model Group, and when I run this

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  prepend SimpleCommand
    ...
    def index
        @group = Group.all
        render json: @group
    end
    ...
    # some other stuff
```

...and then I get a response with array like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1020,
    "name": "НІ-16-1",
    "has_subgroups": true,
    "created_at": "2017-09-29T10:14:08.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-29T10:14:08.000Z"
  }
...
]
```

but I don't want to have those two last fields, so my answer is 
How to get rid of "created_at" and "updated_at" fields in a response?

## UPD:

Found a great solution in original question I've accidentally made a duplicate for. Go ahead and read it

Comment: @Cyzanfar Oh, thanks. I tried to google something like this several times, but never met the answer Yosh linked to. I used the answer from there to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you serve an object to the view as JSON Rails internally calls the function `as_json`. One way to get rid of those two fields is to override that function in your `Group` model:

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
      def as_json(options={})
        { id: id,
          name: name,
          has_subgroups: has_subgroups
        }
      end
  end
```

Or as @MrYoshiji suggested you could filter them out like so:

```
render json: @groups.to_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at])
```

Comment: `as_json` already accepts options like `only: [:some, :field]` and `except: [:other, :field]` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/as_json)

Comment: I *think* what @MrYoshiji is saying (in the other comment thread) is that using the "`as_json` in the model" approach will *always* exclude `created_at` and `updated_at` *any time* the `Group` model is converted to json. This is addressed by your update (using arguments for the `to_json` call). However, you now have an equivalent amount of business logic (such as it is) in the controller as in the approach I proposed.

Comment: @jvillian I confirm. Your (cyczanfar's) solution restrict the available data through the `Group#as_json` call for the whole app. In a different *context*, like `/admin/groups.json` you could need those `updated_at` and `created_at` values

Comment: @jvillian are you sure about that? Calling pluck then as_json. That’s 2 different call.

Comment: @MrYoshiji yes that’s correct. A better way ywould be the ladder

Comment: Am I sure about what?

Answer (score 1):

Rails come with jbuilder by default to generate the json response. You just have to find `group/index.json.jbuilder` and remove `created_at` and `updated_at` inside. And change your controller action to:

```
def index
    @group = Group.all
end
```

or if you need to support other formats:

```
def index
    @group = Group.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
end
```

You can see you don't have to specify anything as Rails will use your jbuilder file by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  prepend SimpleCommand
    ...
  def index
     render json: Group.pluck(:id, :name, :has_subgroups)
  end
end
```

It may not matter to you, but I *think* this approach is faster because it doesn't instantiate all the `Group` objects.

Comment: I guess that's a tradeoff that one needs to consider. If you're going for simplicity and code clarity I wouldn't use this approach as you are manipulating the model data inside the controller. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Cyzanfar the model's role is to handle the business logic, not the data format / serialization. A Serializer would be the perfect place to handle this role

Comment: Yes, I agree that the ideal place would be in a serializer. But definitely not in the controller...

Comment: @Cyzanfar so you would define at the model-level that nowhere in your app you can access the `updated_at`/`created_at` fields' value and NOT define this behaviour in the controller, which is a specific context?

Comment: Not sure I'm following what you're trying to say

Comment: @Cyzanfar A controller is mainly defined for a context, like `/admin/groups` is usually accessed by admins and the available data can vary from the regular `/groups` endpoint meant for end-users. This (jvillian's) solution is contextual, yours (at the model level) is global.